Bending in a wall due to deflection in the beam below
If I have a wall above an opening bearing on a beam that is simply-supported, will the deflection on the beam cause a bending effect on the wall if it is to rest on it? In order to match the shape of the element below, my wall would have to deform at the bottom. Is this bending effect present and is it just controlled by deflection limits?
For reference, here is an image of the behaviour I'm thinking of:
My other question would be: Would the wall be in pure bending or bending and compression from the top (Provided it's loaded).
For the sake of this, Imagine the wall to be precast-concrete and that there is a connection such that the wall and beams' flange are always in contact.


it will be dependent on how the wall is connected to the beam.  Is it not connected but just resting on it, or is it bonded to the beam?

What type of wall will be there? Can it have some shear rigidity?

For the sake of this imagine it is a precast concrete wall, and it is connected such that the bottom of the wall is in constant contact with the beam's flange.

The lintel beam will be designed for the full load above and kept within the deflection limits set by the building code. In reality, the deflection will be much less than calculated because of the arch action that would redirect the loads toward the end supports rather than fully loading the beam.
If excessive deflection occurs, shear cracks likely develop, emitting 45 degrees from the lower corners toward the top edge. At that stage, depending on the material of the wall, the wall will experience tension at the bottom, and compression on the top, or bending at the bottom if it is a reinforced concrete/precast wall.
